# trigger function to refresh remote materialized view on UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

I have the following trigger and trigger function setup in order to refresh a MATERIALIZED VIEW on a remote server every time a local table A gets updated. The MV in turn is created from a foreign table of the local table A. After the trigger runs, the materialized view is updated, however, it is only updated to the state BEFORE the UPDATE happened. I'm not sure why this is the case. Either the trigger function runs before the UPDATE is commited, but that should be what the 'AFTER' part of the trigger is for, right? Or the MV refresh is to fast(?), but adding pg_sleep doesn't change the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.refresh_remote_mv()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
PERFORM dblink_connect('remote_server');
PERFORM dblink_exec(
$$
 REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW m_config;
$$);
PERFORM dblink_disconnect();
RETURN NULL;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpsql;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_remote_refresh
AFTER UPDATE ON m_config
EXECUTE PROCEDURE refresh_remote_mv()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because transaction isolation (your changes will be commited after all the triggers were fired, so another transaction from dblink won't see it).

It would be better to refresh materialized view with some frequency and not for every change. But if you wan't to do it that way you can change your dblink query to async dblink query, it should work then (remember fire it with some delay to be sure that transaction is commited).

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I went with dblink_send_query https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/contrib-dblink-send-query.html